# "Next" behavior and "E165: Cannot go beyond last file"

Tags: key-bindings, multiple-files

I frequently use vim to edit multiple files.  On the command line, I'll type `vim *` or the like, and use `:wn` to move through the files until I get to the end.

Invariably, I get to the last file, and type `:wn` and get the maddening message `E165: Cannot go beyond last file`, when really what I want vim to do is quit at that point (`:wq`).  Is there a configuration that controls this behavior?

Comment: Vim has a simple mind: you ask it to do `:wn` and it does `:wn`. If you want it to do `:wq`, don't tell it to do `:wn`, tell it to do `:wq`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a configuration option to change that behaviour. However you can create a custom command, that catches error E165 and quits in that case. Something like this should work (untested):

```
com! -count -bang Wnext try | <count>wn<bang> | catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E165/ | q | endtry
```

Comment: Hm...I tried this and it didn't work (nothing happened).  I'm not familiar with custom commands in vim, and I didn't see the `com` command looking through the documentation...so I haven't been able to grok/debug this...I'd be happy if you pointed me at documentation....

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `function` like this:

```
function! NextFileOrQuit()
  execute 'try | n | catch | try | wq! | catch | | endtry | endtry'
endfunction
```

And then setup a `normal mode` mapping like so:

```
noremap <Tab> :call NextFileOrQuit()<CR>
```

With this setup, pressing `<Tab>` will move through the files and then
"quit" once it reached the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour of vi. You can do a `:rew` to start with the first file again. In vim you can also use `:bn` and `:bp` to go to the next or previous file. But `:rew` works with any vi variant.

Comment: I'm aware that this is the normal behavior of vim...my question was specifically how to *change* that normal behavior.